# Instance variable being assigned mistakenly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Step model and a MasterStep model. In my controller, I use this and there isn't any assignment that uses MasterStep anywhere.

```
@step = Step.all(:conditions => {:course_id => params[:id], :current_state => :incomplete}, :order => :id).first
```

This is my error log. Notice the MasterCourse:
http://pastie.org/2252224

Here is the relevant method: 
http://pastie.org/pastes/2252198/text

I can't figure out how it's getting a MasterStep object, and in the whole codebase, I can't find anything that's assigning @step to a MasterStep object.

How is that even possible?

Comment: Most of the action is referencing `@step.master_step`... I'm assuming line 110 of the controller is this one: `@course = @step.master_step.master_course`.

Comment: In your current method there is the line `@course = @step.master_step.master_course`. So in your MasterStep model is there a method called master_course?

Comment: I was missing some things in my model, and I should have been doing master_step.master_section.master_course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If @step.master_step is a MasterStep object through your association, it will call that object. Looks like the error is throwing on

```
@course = @step.master_step.master_course
```

Is master_course a method on master_step?

Comment: Yeah, I was just informed of this. Thanks for helping, you deserve the points.